# Getting PSP and Publisher handler working together in Apache2 mod-python

Tags: python, apache2, mod-python

I could just have mod-python working on apache2 for the first time and I could play with PSP and Publisher handler a little by adding either

```
AddHandler mod_python .py
PythonHandler mod_python.publisher
PythonDebug On
```

Or

```
AddHandler mod_python .psp
PythonHandler mod_python.psp
PythonDebug On
```

to /etc/apache2/sites-available/default on Ubuntu lucid lynx.

I tried putting both of them but that didn't work. Now I need both PSP and Publisher to work together.

Something else please, any one know a text editor that supports highlighting for this ? preferably if there is code completion or an IDE.

Comment: `mod_python` is dead. Migrate to a WSGI CMS instead.

Comment: "Currently mod_python is not under active development. This does not mean that it is "dead" as some people have claimed. It smiply means that the code and the project are mature enough when very little is required to maintain it. "

Answer (score 3):

This one works for me:

```
<Directory /var/www>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
        AddHandler mod_python .py
        PythonHandler mod_python.publisher | .py
        AddHandler mod_python .psp .psp_
        PythonHandler mod_python.psp | .psp .psp_
        PythonDebug On
</Directory>
```

For more details read the manual: http://www.modpython.org/live/current/doc-html/dir-handlers-syn.html